# Can I add a WSS Front End with MOSS server?

Tags: topology

Is it possible to add WSS as front end and MOSS as server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not possible to mix WSS and MOSS in the same farm. Furthermore, all servers must be at the same patch level etc.

Comment: Hmm I didn't find any such information on Microsoft website can you point me to any link?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to have a MOSS box as ONE server - and then a WSS box for the Web Front End - that would be seen as "avoiding licensing" by Microsoft.

You could certainly have a farm of WSS boxes - if that's what you mean.   ie. load-balanced and multiple WFE's - just using the free WSS components.

*Licensing is an annoying + tricky game - contact Microsoft to check if your're covered, etc...*

Comment: Yes, you are right I've tested it and you cannot add a WSS Front End in MOSS farm.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure i understand this question.

MOSS is build on top of WSS -you can see WSS as the foundation of SharePoint (this is also what it is called in the new version 2010 of the product).

hth
Anders Rask